# Packages/Extensions like Node.js REPL for a live JavaScript console but for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Something like this one here which is for VS Code - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostfields.nodejs-repl

But for Sublime Text 3. Something that will give me a live or a key combination controlled console for JavaScript. Thank you!

Comment: I'd check out [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL).

Comment: I couldn't quite understand how to use sublimeREPL for Javascript yet. Would you be kind enough to point me towards some tutorials/user guide or some youtube video may be?

Comment: I don't use it myself, sorry. Once it's installed, `Tools > SublimeREPL > Node` should open a nodejs REPL, assuming you have Node installed, though.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks! :)